# Match one to three groups only if they appear in order

Tags: regex

I'd like to match positively strings like "10a3b4c", "10a", "5b4c", "3a6c", but not match "2c1b" (because the letters aren't in alphabetical order) or the empty string.

Attempt: `(\d+a)?(\d+b)?(\d+c)?`
Problem: Matches the empty string. It falsely matches "".

Attempt: `(\d+[abc]){1,3}`
Problem: Doesn't enforce the `a`, `b`, `c` order. It falsely matches "2c1b"

How can this restriction be expressed as a regex?

Comment: Please, explain what makes a string a good match and what not. For instance, why should `4a6c` match but `2c1b` shouldn't? What is the rational?

Comment: @EnricoMariaDeAngelis because `2c1b` is not in the `a`, `b`, `c`, order

Comment: You gave an example of 4 strings you want to match and 1 string you don't want to match, but you never explained what the first four strings have in commond that the fifth string _has not_.

Comment: is the order the only thing that matters?

Comment: @EnricoMariaDeAngelis they have in common that they are "at least one of [these groups] `\d+a`, `\d+b`, `\d+c`, and in that order' the fifth string however is not in that order

Comment: @EnricoMariaDeAngelis the order, and that it doesn't match the empty string. The smallest string it can match is the length 2 `\d[abc]`

Comment: Use `^(?!$)(\d+a)?(\d+b)?(\d+c)?$`

Comment: @RyszardCzech want to make an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
^(?!$)(\d+a)?(\d+b)?(\d+c)?$
```

See [proof](https://regex101.com/r/UwjgP9/1)

**Explanation**

```
                         EXPLANATION
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  ^                        the beginning of the string
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?!                      look ahead to see if there is not:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    $                        before an optional \n, and the end of
                             the string
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-ahead
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \1 (optional
                           (matching the most amount possible)):
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \d+                      digits (0-9) (1 or more times (matching
                             the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    a                        'a'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )?                       end of \1 (NOTE: because you are using a
                           quantifier on this capture, only the LAST
                           repetition of the captured pattern will be
                           stored in \1)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \2 (optional
                           (matching the most amount possible)):
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \d+                      digits (0-9) (1 or more times (matching
                             the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    b                        'b'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )?                       end of \2 (NOTE: because you are using a
                           quantifier on this capture, only the LAST
                           repetition of the captured pattern will be
                           stored in \2)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \3 (optional
                           (matching the most amount possible)):
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \d+                      digits (0-9) (1 or more times (matching
                             the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    c                        'c'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )?                       end of \3 (NOTE: because you are using a
                           quantifier on this capture, only the LAST
                           repetition of the captured pattern will be
                           stored in \3)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  $                        before an optional \n, and the end of the
                           string
```

Comment: This only works if the strings are one on each line.

Comment: @EnricoMariaDeAngelis  That is exact input  OP has.

Comment: the OP doesn't mention anything about the strings being on one line each or not. There's no flag, as far as I know, that makes `^` and `$` match at the word boundaries.

Comment: @minseong, the regex in this answer _cannot_ match if the words are on one line.

Comment: @EnricoMariaDeAngelis it matches one-per-line because Ryszard's regex101 link has the multiline flag enabled.

Comment: `gm` is used to emulate standalone string testing.

Comment: @RyszardCzech's answer assumes that the words are the only content of each line; if they are all on the same line [it does not work](https://regex101.com/r/UwjgP9/2), regardless of the flags.

Comment: However, @minseong, fair enough. Maybe giving all needed information next time is a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work (see it on [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/6n9VxL/1))

```
\b(?=[\dabc]+\b)(\d+a)?(\d+b)?(\d+c)?\b
```

Comment: It's not equivalent. Check on regex101.

Comment: @theonlygusti, `\b` is not the reason why `(?=[\dabc]+\b)` and `(?=.)` have two different effects.